# Is it possible to know the updated time of a Facebook comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I think this has already been asked but without any answer and don't know if it's exactly the same question.

I can retrieve via Graph API or FQL the comments made on a page post, but I would need to know if a comment has been modified and if possible when.

As far as I've seen, I think it's not possible via the Graph API because it only returns the created time and no flag if it has been edited or its updated time.

Ant suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no possibility to achieve that, either via Graph API or FQL:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought...
Do you know if there are any plans to add that functionality soon?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You could have a look at the developer roadmap here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/